# Convert variables from c# to c++

Tags: c#, c++

c#

```
public sealed class RC5
    {
        private readonly uint[] _bufKey = new uint[4];
        private readonly uint[] _bufSub = new uint[26];
};
```

c++(errors)

```
class RC5
{
protected:
        unsigned __int32[] _bufKey = new unsigned __int32[4];
        unsigned __int32[] _bufSub = new unsigned __int32[26];
};
```

Of course I got errors in the c++ code , I don't know how make it right can someone help me please?! Thanks

Comment: Can you include the errors you're getting?

Comment: @Programming Hero unsigned __int32 _bufKey[] = new unsigned __int32[4]; Error :1 IntelliSense: data member initializer is not allowed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In C++ the array "marker" must follow the variable name, not the type name.
2. You have two ways in C++ to instantiate the array:

a) Make it a fix array:

```
class RC5 {
  protected:
    unsigned __int32 _bufKey[4];
    unsigned __int32 _bufSub[26];
};
```

b) Allocate it on the heap:

```
class RC5 {
  public:
    RC5() :
      _bufKey(new unsigned __int32[4]),
      _bufSub(new unsigned __int32[26]) {
    }
    virtual ~RC5() {
      delete [] _bufKey;
      delete [] _bufSub;
    }
  protected:
    unsigned __int32 *const _bufKey;
    unsigned __int32 *const _bufSub;
};
```

Comment: If you’re advocating raw pointers, could you at least mention that there are better C++ ways? Furthermore, your destructor strictly speaking needn’t be `virtual` since the C# class is `sealed` and so doesn’t require inheritance. Apart from that yours is a good answer and since mine seems to be downvoted let’s make yours, which is the highest voted, the best.

Answer (score 2):

All previous answers are wrong – and not just slightly, but completely.

`[]` in C# is `std::vector<>` in C++ and `private` is `private`, not `protected`.

Furthermore, you need to initialize the variables in the constructor, and `new` isn’t used.

```
class RC5 {
private:

    std::vector<unsigned> _bufKey;
    std::vector<unsigned> _bufSub;

public:

    RC5() : _bufKey(4), _bufSub(16) { }
};
```

This requires the standard header `<vector>` to work.

If the size of the fields is static then using `std::array<>` (or, if you insist, a static C array) is also an option (this requires a modern C++ compiler):

```
class RC5 {
private:

    std::array<unsigned, 4> _bufKey;
    std::array<unsigned, 16> _bufSub;
};
```

That said, [**get a C++ book**](http://tinyurl.com/so-cxxbooks). Neither Stack Overflow nor such examples can teach you basic C++ syntax.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph i know private is private but in c# it's sealed thats why i made it protected

Comment: @MixedCoder But `protected` and `sealed` mean completely different things and making it protected here *makes no sense*, *especially* if it isn’t meant for inheritance (that’s what `sealed` means).

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph then what is = to sealed in c++

Comment: @MixedCoder: unfortunately, there is no direct equivalent. To prevent inheritance in C++ you need to make either the constructor or the destructor `private`. But then you can no longer use the class normally, you need to provide a special method of creating the class – so this isn’t a viable solution most of the time! Instead of making your class `sealed`, in C++ you would clearly document the fact that your class cannot be inherited.

Comment: @MixedCoder: I think you are going to have a really hard time coding C++ if you assume that it is anything like C#. In this question alone we have seen several important differences. Listen to this guy; get a good book.

Answer (score 1):

You can't initialize members in C++ directly in class definition, you must set them inside a method (usually constructor).

This is because class definition can be loaded several times in different files (classes are usually defined in header, headers are usually included in other headers or CPP files), which would lead to multiple execution of one piece of code.

This is solution:

```
class RC5
{
protected:
    unsigned* _bufKey;
    unsigned* _bufSub;
public:
    RC5(){
        this->_bufKey = new unsigned[4];
        this->_bufSub = new unsigned[26];
    }
};
```

OR this

```
class RC5
{
protected:
    unsigned _bufKey[4];
    unsigned _bufSub[26];
};
```

Of course good practice is to separate method body from class definition, but that is easy to do.

Comment: Errors: IntelliSense: expected an identifier,IntelliSense: expected a ';',IntelliSense: expected a ';',IntelliSense: class "RC5" has no member "_bufSub",IntelliSense: class "RC5" has no member "_bufKey"

Comment: After the change this should at least compile but it’s bad C++ for a number of different reasons and it’s not a direct translation.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates the real problem:

> data member initializer is not allowed

You cannot declare a member of a class in C++ and initialize it in the same line. Instead you will have to declare the members and initialize them separately (in a constructor):

```
class RC5
{
protected:
        unsigned __int32[] _bufKey;
        unsigned __int32[] _bufSub;

public:
        RC5();
};

RC5::RC5()
{
    this._bufKey = new unsigned __int32[4];
    this._bufSub = new unsigned __int32[26];
}
```

(My C++ syntax is rusty, so apologies for any syntax errors.)

Comment: Errors:IntelliSense: expression must have class type,IntelliSense: expected an identifier,IntelliSense: expected a ';',IntelliSense: expected a ';'

Answer (score -1):

The C++ type is, **unsigned int**.

Also note that, you can't initialize C++ arrays this way  using new. You have to use Pointers and assign memory to that.

Comment: unsigned __int32 _bufKey[] = new unsigned __int32[4]; Error :1 IntelliSense: data member initializer is not allowed

Comment: My initial post implied that "__int32" is not a type in C++. I guess the PO was discussing about how to initialize. In that case, the method described by mzabsky should be followed.